# Additional Optimizations for Convolutional Models On Inferencing

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, tensorflow, optimization, batch-normalization

I am aware of several ways to optimize a convolutional (or any) model after training to make inferencing quicker. I am currently implementing [BatchNormalization Folding](https://scortex.io/batch-norm-folding-an-easy-way-to-improve-your-network-speed/) and removing Dropout layers from the network. I am also aware of [post training quantization](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_float16_quant) (specifically 16-bit quantization for use on GPU).

Are there other layer optimization techniques that I can use other than quantization?

My current model uses, Conv2D, Activation(relu), BatchNormalization, Dropout, Dense layers.

Basic mnist Convnet metrics for 10K images, batch size of 1: (All have 98.92% accuracy)

- Original Network: 49.3s
- Folded Network: 33.37s
- Quantized Original: 7.449s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into [models pruning](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning). There are several [techniques](https://towardsdatascience.com/model-compression-via-pruning-ac9b730a7c7b) out here, and all of them aim to reduce the amount of parameters of a model without affecting its performance metrics. Of course less parameters means less calculation and therefore faster inference time.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't looked into pruning much because it's not as straightforward as the others I've done. I'll look more into it now.